# how can i find "smallest eigenvalue" o a plate with python scripting in abaqus?

Tags: python, eigenvalue, abaqus

i write a python script to modeling and analysis a plate for buckling.
i need the minimum eigenvalue for run the other script for RIKS analysis.
how can i find "smallest eigenvalue" with python scripting in abaqus?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = [3,1,4,5]
print min(foo)

outputs => 1
```

Comment: ok axel
but how can i read the eigenvalue from odb of buckling analysis?

Answer (score 0):

```
datFullPath = PathDir+FileName+'.dat'


myOutdf = open(datFullPath,'r')
stline=' MODE NO      EIGENVALUE\n'
lines = myOutdf.readlines()

ss=0

for i in range(len(lines)-1):
    if lines[i] == stline :
        print lines[i]
        ss=i

f1=lines[ss+3]
MinEigen=float(f1[15:24])
myOutdf.close()

MinEigen
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import abaqus odb work related modules

from odbAccess import *

# Read the odb file, change name and path as per your requirement
### This is a typical procedure to read history-outputs, as
### frequency etc. information is not available as field output

odb = openOdb(path =JobName+'.odb')

a=odb.rootAssembly
step=odb.steps['Step-1']
frames=step.frames
numframes=len(frames)
i=0

MinEigen=[]


for frame in frames :
    f1=frame.description
    if len(f1[28:48])>1:
        MinEg=float(f1[28:48])
        if MinEg>0.0:
            MinEigen.append (MinEg)


print MinEigen,min(MinEigen)


fwall=open("EIGENX.txt", 'a')
fwall.write(str(min(MinEigen))+'\n')
fwall.close()

odb.close()
##stop
```